# Is a desktop needed to set up a private cloud?

Tags: cloud, openstack

I installed ubuntu server 13.10

- FTP and SFTP server work OK
- SSH via terminal works as well
- no desktop - only terminal input / output

Now I want to install a private cloud
- with calendar and contact synchronization.

What are the best next steps ?

Do I need the unity-desktop ?
If yes, how can I install it from within the server ?
- and then ?
If not, I would need the terminal commands to proceed.

All of what I read so far, required a desktop

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Devstack is the simplest way to set up a private cloud without using a GUI, and the instructions are available at the [OpenStack website](http://www.openstack.org/software/start/).  You will need to [make sure git is installed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-12-04) with `sudo apt-get install git-core`, [Download DevStack] with `git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git` whose repository contains a script that installs OpenStack and templates for configuration files. Then, start the install with 
`cd devstack; ./stack.sh`

Comment: Wouldn't OpenStack be a bit overkill for calendar and contact synchronization? Just a thought...

Comment: OP asked for 'Now I want to install a private cloud - with calendar and contact synchronization.' If he wants a cloud, then perhaps there is some other reason beyond calendar & contacts. English, she is such an imprecise lingo.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a desktop installed to run any web based services, but you will probably need to [set up a LAMP server](http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-server-apache-mysql-php-ubuntu-13-10-server/). As for the cloud services you are looking to set up, I would take a look at [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/), it is a nice fully featured suite  (Calendar, Contacts, Dropbox like file sync with document editing, etc...)

You can find simple installation instructions [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-owncloud-6-on-ubuntu-debian-centos-fedora-opensuse-and-derivates/)

And Configuration information can be found in the Documentation Centre [here](http://doc.owncloud.org/)

Hope it Helps.